# CrtDbgBreak issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I used to work with the Release version of VS2010 and suddenly, when switching to the Debug version, I get a breakpoint error message and it's redirected to the file dbgrptt which exists at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\dbgrptt.c

The displayed error message is:

```
 ex.exe has triggered a breakpoint
```

This is where is redirects after showing the error message.

```
_CRTIMP void _cdecl _CrtDbgBreak(
void
)
{
__debugbreak(); 
}
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug version of the CRT detected that something went wrong. The debug version sacrifices runtime speed in order to do more expensive checking so that it can detect such situations. They are typically caused by a bug in your code. In other words, you an error that happened not to manifest in the release build - so far.

How do you get rid of it? Fix the error. Run your program under the debugger, and when you reach the error, check the call stack. Go up the call stack until you find out what happened. Chances are, you are doing something like using a dangling reference/pointer, or an invalidated iterator, or you access something out of bounds.

Comment: That was indeed an invalidated iterator! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/c-cpp-assertions):

> Assertion statements compile only if `_DEBUG` is defined. Otherwise, the
> compiler treats assertions as null statements. Therefore, assertion
> statements impose no overhead or performance cost in your final
> Release program, and allow you to avoid using `#ifdef` directives.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).